# SQL Query - Ensure a row exists for each value in ()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Currently struggling with finding a way to validate 2 tables (efficiently lots of rows for Table A)

I have two tables

**Table A**

```
 ID 
 A
 B 
 C
```

**Table matched**

```
ID Number
A   1
A   2
A   9
B   1
B   9
C   2
```

I am trying to write a SQL Server query that basically checks to make sure for every value in Table A there exists a row for a variable set of values ( 1, 2,9)

The example above is incorrect because t should have for every record in A a corresponding record in Table matched for each value (1,2,9).  The end goal is:

**Table matched**

```
ID Number
A   1
A   2
A   9
B   1
B   2
B   9
C   1
C   2
C   9
```

I know its confusing, but in general for every X in ( some set ) there should be a corresponding record in Table matched.  I have obviously simplified things.

Please let me know if you all need clarification.

Comment: Is there always three values? Are the values always 1,2, and 9?

Comment: No there are actually 17 values.. and they are not sequential. (1,3,4,5 7, etc)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT a.id
    FROM TABLE_A a
    JOIN TABLE_B b ON b.id = a.id
   WHERE b.number IN (1, 2, 9)
GROUP BY a.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.number) = 3
```

The DISTINCT in the COUNT ensures that duplicates (IE: A having two records in TABLE_B with the value "2") from being falsely considered a correct record.  It can be omitted if the `number` column either has a unique or primary key constraint on it.

The `HAVING COUNT(...)` ***must*** equal the number of values provided in the `IN` clause.

Comment: I think this will work, stupid simple(frustrating).  Testing now.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nix: I suppose I could make it more convoluted? :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp table of values you want. You can do this dynamically if the values 1, 2 and 9 are in some table you can query from.

Then, `SELECT FROM tempTable WHERE NOT IN (SELECT * FROM TableMatched)`

Comment: I need to make sure for every row all values in IN exist in the match table.  Wont that just tell me if I have values that aren't in there?

Comment: What do you want to have happen if there are records missing? My SELECT won't return any records if all of the desired records exist in TableMatched. That would be passing the test, right? If there are records returned here, then the test fails. Do you want this SQL to INSERT the missing records?

Comment: @DOK no, the test does not fail. If it returns records, then it can be that it just has extra records, which was not forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I had this situation one time. My solution was as follows.

In addition to TableA and TableMatched, there was a table that defined the rows that should exist in TableMatched for each row in TableA. Let’s call it TableMatchedDomain.

The application then accessed TableMatched through a view that controlled the returned rows, like this:

```
create view TableMatchedView
select  a.ID,
        d.Number,
        m.OtherValues      
from    TableA a
        join TableMatchedDomain d
        left join TableMatched m on m.ID = a.ID and m.Number = d.Number
```

This way, the rows returned were always correct. If there were missing rows from TableMatched, then the Numbers were still returned but with OtherValues as null. If there were extra values in TableMatched, then they were not returned at all, as though they didn't exist. By changing the rows in TableMatchedDomain, this behavior could be controlled very easily. If a value were removed TableMatchedDomain, then it would disappear from the view. If it were added back again in the future, then the corresponding OtherValues would appear again as they were before.

The reason I designed it this way was that I felt that establishing an invarient on the row configuration in TableMatched was too brittle and, even worse, introduced redundancy. So I removed the restriction from groups of rows (in TableMatched) and instead made the entire contents of another table (TableMatchedDomain) define the correct form of the data.